# What is the best test two compare samples with continuous results when there is not normality

Tags: t-test, shapiro-wilk-test

I have a sample (n=200) and I have the results of two in silico prediction tests. Results are continuous and very similar but I want to confirm this statistically.

I have done shapiro test to see if samples follow a normal distribution and p value of one sample was 1.73-e25 so, they dont follow a normal distribution.

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: What do you want to test? What do you mean that you want to confirm statistically that the distributions are similar?

Comment: I want to confirm that results are significantly equal although there is minimun variation between the results of the two tests

Comment: What does "significantly equal" mean to you? There are many misconceptions about this kind of notion.

Comment: It would also help to know what the data generation process is. What kind of distribution could model your results? Are they on fixed domain, e.g. 0...1 or half-open, e.g. $\left(0,\,\infty\right)$. Also you should think about what is significant difference for your use-case. For example, if you measured enough samples you could probably prove that oak toothpicks are heavier than birch ones, but it will not make a significant difference to the weight of the burger where you use the toothpick to keep it upright